What differentiates a 1500W space heater from reaching the temperatures that a 1500W kiln/furnace does?
What differentiates a 1500W space heater from reaching the temperatures that a 1500W kiln/furnace does? These are both resistive loads, each dissipating 1500 watts of power, but one is clearly a higher temperature than the other. Is this primarily just due to the fact that the kiln has insulation and the space heater doesn't?

Depending on the design of your space heater, there may be parts of it that get as hot as the kiln. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C9ZP7GDW/

Yes. Chemomechanics gave the mathematically thorough answer, but in plain language the temperature in a given volume depends on the heat flow into and the heat flow out of it (and the size of the volume, what it is composed of, and time).  As you guessed, the insulation and geometry make the difference.
I think your wiring question is outside the scope of this channel.

Thank you so much! So any 1500 watts of power dissipated inside a box will generate the same amount of heat; the wire is just engineering considerations

Yes. Per the heat equation, the equilibrium temperature $T$ of a region of resistive heating satisfies
$$J^2\rho+k\nabla^2 T-\frac{h}{P}(T-T_\infty)-\frac{\sigma\epsilon}{P}(T^4-T^4_\infty)=0,$$
with thermal conductivity $k$, current density $J$, resistivity $\rho$, convection coefficient $h$, characteristic perimeter length $P$ (volume per surface area), surrounding temperature $T_\infty$, Stefan–Boltzmann coefficient $\sigma$, and emissivity $\epsilon$.
That is, the heat generation is balanced by the total heat loss from conduction (downward curvature of the temperature profile gives $\nabla^2T<0$), convection, and radiation.
At constant current, blocking airflow, mirroring back any radiation, decreasing the thermal conductivity, and increasing the conduction distance, for example, all tend to increase the steady-state temperature. This is appropriate for a kiln and inappropriate for a space heater, which—because the aim is heat transport to the surroundings—lacks insulation, mirrors the heat toward the user, and sometimes even adds a fan to boost convection.

I'm trying to design a kiln and for a given resistance and voltage (and same environmental conditions), would it be better to use shorter smaller gauge resistance wire or thicker larger gauge resistance wire?

If you're considering changing the wire diameter, how will you keep the resistance constant? By also changing the wire length? How are you defining "better"?
